# How to use freedict dictionaries?

Tags: dictionary

I have installed some dictionaries.

[image]

What is the application to use ?

Gnome dictionary and Artha are also installed but both just give English definitions to English words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Goldendict** is the thing.

After installing it in Synaptic Manager and also the dictionaries as in the image from the question, start Goldentict and it will read the database.

[image]

After in opens all those separate dictionaries appear in it

[image]

When selecting a dictionary on that bar it takes some time to load. The quality of these supplementary dictionaries is usually mediocre.