# Add new dictionaries to Gnome dictionary?

Tags: dictionary

How to add sources to this dictionary seems simple enough but  what is to be written there?
It is only in English and I would like to have other dictionaries - see [my related question](https://askubuntu.com/q/222200/47206)

[image]

Comment: Are you only wondering about what to use in the highlighted “Description” field or do you ask what all fields in the depicted form should contain? Do you have a dictionary server to which you would like to connect or (since you are referring to the other question) would you like to know how to use locally installed dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

This link might answer some of your questions about working with gnome dictionary client:
http://arachnoid.com/linux/dictionary.html

Also and excellent Askubuntu thread in here:
[Offline dictionary with pronunciation and usages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170775/offline-dictionary-with-pronunciation-and-usages)